# how to hide facebook "social plugin" link from facebook likebox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I want to hide the developer link "Social Plugin" link from facebook like box, Can any one does before, 
Thanks

Comment: May be change of height will work

Comment: Its my pleasure to help here @vengadesh

Answer (score 0):

using inline css to change the height of likebox like the follow if your like box width is 300px

```
style=" height:234px;border-width: 2px;border-style: solid;"
```

let me know  , does this works

Answer (score 0):

To hide the developers link "Social Plugin" i used CSS like below here:
Give it a height that wil be less than the actual box. and then simple use overflow hidden.
I know its not very clean, but it works.

```
.fb-like-box.fb_iframe_widget {

height: 202px;
overflow: hidden;

}
```